# Cannot login to Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system

I am creating my own Drupal theme, but I logged out to see what it looks like and I can't log back in to change the settings.

I went to `/?q=user` and that didn't work either. The theme I have only displays the site name and slogan so far. Can I change this in a file on the server? Or do I have to uninstall drupal and reinstall it?

My URL is [aidrupal.freeiz.com](http://aidrupal.freeiz.com/)

Comment: cut paste the theme you've been working on on a different folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change back to a default theme via the settings.php file.  Here is a thread that explains how: http://drupal.org/node/87390

Or, as per Jonathan's comment, paste the files from the default theme over yours.

Comment: I renamed the folder and I could see a very unstyled version with a login form. I wasn't allowed to edit the `settings.php` file. I couldn't save it.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into HTML source of the link you provided, it seems that your `page.tpl.php` or `node.tpl.ph`p files are not parsing correctly.

Please go through them and see whether there is any error in these files.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, the only page I have is page.tpl.php so far!